# Using an angular build inside Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, angularjs, lightning-web-components

Can I take an Angular build and using inside Salesforce within a lightning component?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using lightning:container.
From the docs - 
lightning:container allows you to use an app developed with a third-party framework, such as AngularJS or React, in an Aura component. Upload the app as a static resource.
Your application must have a launch page, which is specified with the lightning:container src attribute. By convention, the launch page is index.html, but you can specify another launch page by adding a manifest file to your static resource. 
source : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_js.htm